# IntelliJ shows wrongly not resolved imports

Tags: android, import, intellij-idea

Since yesterday my IntelliJ IDE is a bit messed up.

The imports, **for example** all of the `android.support.v4` or `com.google.analytics` package, are shown as not resolved and red highlighted in the editor. Nevertheless compiling and running the project works fine.

**Any ideas how to fix this? It's a mayor blocker.**

Comment: Have you cleaned project and restarted Intellij etc.

Comment: I rebuild the project several times, restarted IntelliJ and restarted my PC.

Comment: **android-support-v4.jar** is added for sure.?

Comment: can you install the appropriate support library (the newest)

Comment: Yep, the project runs fine. All imports which are not Android default ones are not recognized from the editor but from the compiler.

Comment: @user1969053 It's the newest. And not only the support aren't resolved in the editor, all which are default ones from Android aren't recognized as resolved (e.g Google Analytics, ACRA, etc).

Comment: Does `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart help?

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot! Post it as answer, I'll accept it and upvote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case everything builds and works fine, just not the editor highlighting, the first thing to try is `File` | `Invalidate Caches` and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the selected answer but it did not work. Instead I noticed that putting the cursor on the missing Class (marked in red) and waiting for the suggestion tooltip, it has an option of: `add library 'Gradle:yourmissinglabrary' to your classpath`

Once you click that option the `cannot resolve symbol 'ClassName'` dissapear